# How to make Drawerlayout hamburger icon from not clicking ?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I want to disable the hamburger button . it should be visible but not clickable . Note that I already tried setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false) . This will disable the whole hamburger icon .I dont want that. I want hamburger icon to be visible but greyedout or gone for clicking during network operation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use View.setClickable(boolean) on the DrawerLayout instance. 
It doesn't change looks, but make the view to be not touchable (or touchable on setClickable(true) ).

```
drawerLayout.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: @rana Use this. `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);`